# generate me the .gcda files for code coverage

Tags: ios, unit-testing, xcode5, code-coverage

I am new to code coverage , and I followed the steps from the following site http://www.bubblefoundry.com/blog/2013/09/generating-ios-code-coverage-reports/. 
When I run the app and test it all are working and also I am getting .gcda files in the following directory **~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyAppTests.build/Objects-normal/i386/**
But when I try to get the code coverage , terminal gives me the error that *no .gcda files* found. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How are you trying to 'get the code coverage'?

Comment: i got the code coverage atlast the following link helps me http://www.bubblefoundry.com/blog/2013/09/generating-ios-code-coverage-reports/

Comment: Thanks for solving my problem. Use __gcov_flush() (regardless of xcode)